# Is passing array as GET parameter a security issue?

Tags: security, web

I college of mine just denied passing repetitive values as a get parameter because it was a security issue. I google the term he mentioned "parameter pollution", but that is the first time I am hearing of this. Is it really a thing we should be concerned. I am working on a ASP.NET MVC project but it doesn't matter - this question affects all web frameworks. So is passing an array as a get parameter like `?key[]=v1&key[]=v2` wrong and if "yes" - how.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_(OTG-INPVAL-004), it explains the security issue about passing arrays through a request.

> By itself, this is not necessarily an indication of vulnerability.
>   However, if the developer is not aware of the problem, the presence of
>   duplicated parameters may produce an anomalous behavior in the
>   application that can be potentially exploited by an attacker. As often
>   in security, unexpected behaviors are a usual source of weaknesses
>   that could lead to HTTP Parameter Pollution attacks in this case. To
>   better introduce this class of vulnerabilities and the outcome of HPP
>   attacks, it is interesting to analyze some real-life examples that
>   have been discovered in the past.

In a nutshell, passing an array in a get request exposes the request to the user and he can easily modify it, but an advanced user can also modify the parameters of a post request. So both are not secure with http. I strongly recommand you to use https if you are not using it.